# Acceso denegado en phpmyadmin en ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin, xampp

Instalé XAMPP para ubuntu 18.04, cuando inicio XAMPP con el comando `sudo ./lampp start` obtengo las siguientes salidas en la terminal.

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.2.9-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache.../opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
/opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL.../opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD.../opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
ok.
```

Para iniciar tanto el servidor Apache como MySQL. Cuando ingreso `localhost`, no hay problemas. Sin embargo, al ingresar a `localhost/phpmyadmin`, obtengo la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Suena a que no tienes netstat instalado. Mira esto:  https://linuxconfig.org/bash-netstat-command-not-found-debian-ubuntu-linux

Comment: http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/

Comment: @blov80 cambió la salida al ejecutar el comando de inicilización de XAMPP, pero sigue sin tener acceso al phpmyadmin

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez eso no funcionó

Comment: es mysql el que no está iniciando o php no tiene acceso. prueba con __/etc/init.d/mysql status__

Comment: esto obtuve para mi cuenta de usuario `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`, y como usuario root `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era que tenía `mysql-server` corriendo, por que lo solución fue

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

y luego correr `sudo ./lampp restart`

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: como te diste cuenta de que ese era el problema amigo? me pasaba lo mismo que a ti y resolvi con tu respuesta.

Comment: @JulianProg se me ocurrio revisar que procesos estaban corriendo en los puertos que usa lampp, y me salía que mysql estaba corriendo ya en ese puerto. Entonces me cuenta que existía una versión de mysql corriendo ya en ubuntu, me imagino que las versiones nuevas de ubunte viene con mysql ya, dale una un voto a la pregunta o la respuesta :)