# problemas con servicio MySQL en linux

Tags: mysql, linux, lampp

necesito hacer unas pruebas en local, asi que instale `lampp`, `ssh` y `MySQL`, pero al momento de ejecutar:

`mysql -u root`

me muestra el error de la imagen, ese archivo `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` no existe.

Intente reiniciando los servicios `MySQL` y el `LAMPP` pero sigue el mismo problema. Por ultimo desinstale `MySQL` siguiendo un tutorial para hacer una desinstalacion totalmente completa, instale nuevamente y nada.

Alguna idea? que podria hacer? gracias de antemano.

Comment: No se supone que la M de LAMPP es ya MySql?

Comment: tuve que instalar mysql aparte proque cuando habia instalado solamente el LAMPP y ejecutaba el comando mysql -u root me mostraba esto: sudo apt install mysql-client-core-5.7   sudo apt install mariadb-client-core-10.1 , asi que procedí a instalarlo.

Answer (score 0):

En su dia me apunté esta direccion ya que me pasó lo mismo que a ti. Es la web inglesa, espero que lo entiendas.
[Enlace a solucion de StackOverflow en](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq)

Comment: eso ya la había intentado y no me funcionó.

Comment: No debes enlazar como respuesta una del sitio en ingles. Debes traducir la respuesta, o dejar el enlace en un comentario para que alguien lo traduzca. Mira por favor [answer]

Comment: @JulianProg fijate lo importante que es que digas que intentaste o probaste, para que la solucion no sea justamente algo que ya hiciste ;)

Comment: Si, se me olvido agregar eso a mi pregunta, la voy a editar.

Comment: intento matando los procesos como lo explican en 1 de las respuestas de ese link q m dejaron y logre entrar a mysql, ahora el problema es que cuando intento acceder a localhost/phpmyadmin me muestra dice: Acceso denegado, no se pero creo que hay un conflicto entre mysql y lampp o algo asi, porque luego segui lo que explican en este link:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/205155/acceso-denegado-en-phpmyadmin-en-ubuntu-18-04 y el problema de phpmyadmin se resuelve pero vuelvo al problema inicial, no puedo acceder a mysql por consola con el comando mysql -u root. alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con

```
sudo pkill -f mysql  # Para "matar" todos los procesos que tengan que ver con mysql
sudo service mysql start  # para inicia el servidor de mysql.
```